# retrieve an array of id's from get_categories

Tags: php, arrays, get, categories

I am trying to retrieve an array of ID's from:

```
$categories = get_categories(array('hide_empty' =>false,'taxonomy'=>'product_cat', 'child_of' => 15));
```

When i check $categories with var_dump, i get everything.
But only the term_ID is needed.

I have tried the following foreach loop:

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        $option = $category->cat_ID;
                        var_dump($option);
                      }
```

var_dump now shows:

```
int(16) int(37) int(41) int(42) int(17) int(38) int(29) int(40) int(30) int(31) int(32) int(33) int(34) int(36)
```

I assume that this would be the desired array. How can i pass this array to a condition later on?
theo

After much confusion i want to straighten up this question and post what worked for me:

```
<?php 
$categoryX = [];
$parentID = XX; //id of parent
$category = get_categories( array(

        'hide_empty' =>false,
        'taxonomy'=>'product_cat',
        'child_of' => $parentID 
        ) );

        foreach( $categoriySort as $category ) {
        array_push($categorySortiment, $category->cat_ID);
        } 
        array_push($categorySortiment, $parentID);
```

Then i can assign the variable $categoryX that holds an array with all the ID's to a condition later on.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where would you like to pass this array? To some function? Also, are you referring to the `int(16) int(37) int(41) int(42) int(1)...` >> this array?

Comment: i am adding the array to an if /elseif statement in order to display different navigations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following declares a new array, then iterates through the categories adding the $category->cat_ID value to the $categoryIDArray using PHP's [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function. This results in an array containing just the category ID's.

```
  $categoryIDArray = [];

  foreach ($categories as $category) {
    array_push($categoryIDArray, $category->cat_ID);
  }
```

You can then simply pass the $categoryIDArray into whatever function you need like so:

```
$categories = getCategories( $categoryIDArray );
```

Comment: $categories = getCategories( $categoryIDArray ); or rather

Comment: $categories = get_categories( $categoryIDArray ); outputs an array, yes, but not the id's i am looking for. $categoryIDArray looks better but also doesn't do the job. I guess i stick to simply adding the id's manually. Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not totally clear about what it is you are trying to achieve but perhaps this function could help you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php. You could use it something like this:

Comment: if (in_array($catID, $categoryIDArray)) {
    echo "$catID was found inside $categoryIDArray";
}

Comment: sorry, if i wasn't clear enough. For the time being i have to go to dinner, but i'll be back and check your links. Thanks

Comment: i tried that one too, but in $catID is undefined and returns an error. I'll try to explain my goal a bit better. I am looking to get something like this: $category=array(1,2,3,4,5,etc....) With this info i then display a navigation. My idea was, to let wordpress do the work instead of hard coding the variable.

Comment: sorry, i cannot upvote your answer, for i don't have enough permissions and then i just didn't work. The logic is clear but the code has mistakes

Comment: I gave it another try and i have to apologize for the confusion. The code works. I upvoted your answer. Thanks for your care

Answer (score 0):

$all_Categories = array();
foreach ($categories as $category) { $all_Categories = $category->cat_ID;}

Comment: The var_dump function displays structured information about variables/expressions including its type and value.

Comment: i tried that one, but it didn'work out. Thanks for your help anyway.